# Programmatically Uncheck a Checkbox in a wx.CheckListBox

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Is there a method to uncheck a checkbox in a wx.CheckListBox as I need to implement an "uncheck all" button, can't seem to find anything... although there is number of methods for setting a checkbox/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an optional "check" argument for Check() - see http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxchecklistbox.html#wxchecklistboxcheck

Example: `clb.Check(itemnum, check=False)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for cb in mycblist.Checked:
   mycblist.Check(cb, False)
```

Comment: Same as jermeys solution who answered first so I marked his as the accepted... +1 Thanks all the same though

Comment: ninja'd! I always hate it when that happens... thanks for the upvote though!

Answer (score 0):

Use [void wxCheckListBox::Check Check(int item, bool check = true)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxchecklistbox.html#wxchecklistboxcheck) to do the unchecking of each of the items. The item count should be available through the [unsigned int wxControlWithItems::GetCount GetCount() const](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxchecklistbox.html#wxchecklistboxcheck) method (wxCheckListBox is derived from wxControlWithItems).